# Remove repeated adjacent characters in a string

Tags: matlab, function, sorting, find, unique

I have a doubt about a function in MATLAB.

I have this, for example:

```
a=['9' '9' '9' '-' '-' '1' '1' '2' '3' '3' '5' '6' '7' '7' '7' '9' '6' '4' '-' '-' '3']

a =

999--1123356777964--3
```

And I want to transform that, to this:

```
9-123567964-3
```

Delete the adjacent char that repeats, i tried to use:

```
unique(a,'stable')
```

But this function deletes some chars, that are not adjacent.

**Is there any function that does this operation?**

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you change the title to something like "Remove repeated adjacent characters in a string", so that future readers can find your question more easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a(logical([1 diff(double(a))]))
```

*Explanation*: chars are transformed to numbers with [`double`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/double.html). Then [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) gives nonzero for each element that differs from the preceding one. The result is used as a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to select elements from `a`. The first element of `a` is always retained (note that `diff` gives a vector with one less element than `a`).

Comment: @MotorageLegit Glad about that :-)

Comment: This is a smart solution so +1, however to make it stable for nan I would suggest `a([true, diff(double(a))~=0])`. Thanks again for the solution.